# R keep only data frames in a list of list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm beginning with R so I'm not really good at searching relevant answer for my question. I am sorry if similar questions have been asked.

I have a list made of data frames and lists.
I'd like to know how to keep only data frames so that I can bind them together to produce on huge data frame.

here I give you an example :

```
 L1 <- list(c(1, "abc", 3))
 L2 <- list(c("b","d"))
 L3 <- list(L1,L2)
 brand <-  c("A","B","C","D")
 price <-  c(1,1,3,7)
 df <- data.frame(brand , price)
 brand2 <-  c("E","F","G","H")
 price2 <-  c(20,3,5,10)
 df2 <-  data.frame(brand2, price2)
 L4 <- list(df, L3, df2)

 finaldf <- do.call("rbind.fill", L4)
```

Unfortunately I got this error : Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames

So I know that the problem is that there is a list in that list L4. In my real data, there are even several lists in the big list. So can anyone tell me how to get rid of these lists inside the big list ? Thank you very very much !

Comment: Just to clarify: do you only want to extract those items in your lists that are data.frame and ignore vectors and then bind those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out which list entries are not data.frames like so:

```
is_df <- sapply(L4, is.data.frame)

finaldf <- do.call("rbind.fill", L4[is_df])
```

Alterntatively,

`do.call("rbind.fill", Filter(is.data.frame, L4))`

Comment: I think the issue here is that OP may have some data.frames that are nested within lists that they'd still like to extract, which would fail the first statement here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index to subset your list like so:

```
# Subset list
index <- sapply(L4, is.data.frame)
```

and then use it to make your final data.frame like so:

```
finaldf <- do.call("rbind", L4[index])
```

Keep in mind that in order for this to work both dataframes have to have the same column names, so when you create `df2` you should specify the column names like so:

```
df2 <-  data.frame(brand = brand2, price = price)
```

... before you even do the above.